# EF Distinct on IQueryable doesn't remove duplicates

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have a generic class that is supposed to filter, order, project and paginate an `IQueryable` by calling this method:

```
public async Task<PagedResult<TResult>> GetFilteredOrderedPageAsync<TResult>(IQueryable<TSource> source,
            IFilterModel filterModel,
            ISortModel sortModel,
            int page, int pageSize,
            Expression<Func<TSource, TResult>> converter)
            where TResult : class 
        {
            var filtered = Filter(source, filterModel);

            var projected = filtered
                .Select(converter)
                .Distinct();

            var ordered = Sort<TResult>(projected, sortModel);

            var result = await GetPageAsync<TResult>(ordered, page, pageSize, converter);

            return result;
        }
```

I am calling `Distinct()` here

```
        var projected = filtered
            .Select(converter)
            .Distinct();
```

to remove any duplicates that may appear after projection.

My assumption was that EF6 would generate something like

```
SELECT DISTINCT Col1, Col2, Col3 FROM (SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4 FROM SOME_TABLE WHERE <some conditions on co1, col2, col3, col4 ...>)
```

i.e. that it would apply `DISTINCT` to the projection, so, if there are two rows with same col1, col2, col3 but different col4, only one row would make it into the result. 
However, the SQL that I get looks like this:

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4 FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4 FROM SOME_TABLE)
```

- no projection, and DISTINCT is shifted into a subquery, as if I were doing this:

```
var projected = filtered                    
                .Distinct()
                .Select(converter)
```

I want this service to be a generic, i.e. potentially working with any `TSource` and `TResult`, but looks like there's some pitfall here and my understanding of what EF does is not correct.

What's going on here?

**UPDATE**

I believe the problem is in my converter. I used the following function to generate the lambda expression passed to `Select`:

```
public class ProvidersViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Rate Rate { get; set; } 
    publi QA QA { get; set; }
    ...
    public static Expression<Func<ProviderJoinRateAndQA, ProvidersViewModel>> FromProvider(bool showRateAndQA) 
    {
       return x => new ProvidersViewModel {
        Name = x.Name, 
        Rate = showRateAndQA ? new Rate { Amount = x.Rate.Amount ... } : null,
        Rate = showRateAndQA ? new QA { Grade = x.QA.Grade ... } : null
    };
}
```

}

`ProviderJoinRateAndQA` is a join of providers, their rates and QAs. Each `Provider` can have multiple services, rates and qas. In some cases I want view model to hide the rate and QA info. I assumed I could do it by assigning a `null` to `Rate` and `QA` properties, but it doesn't seem to work:  `Distinct` works incorrectly.
After I replaced
    Rate = showRateAndQA ? new QA { Grade = x.QA.Grade ... } : null 
with
    Rate = new QA { Grade = showRateAndQA ? x.QA.Grade : null  ... },

`Distinct` worked correctly.

Apparently EF didn't like my assigning `null` to object in my lambda.

Comment: Looks like a bug. Can you post an executable repro? The EF will need that for a fix anyway.

Comment: I'm sort of new, no idea how to post executable repro correctly. Just post the code or drop the project somewhere and link to it?

Comment: Are you sure of this? Are you sure your converter is correct?

Comment: From some tests, I've noted that if one of the columns you make the distinct on is the primary key, the distinct isn't done/it is moved. This is quite clear... If there are no joins, a distinct on a primary key is a no-op (it doesn't do anything)

Comment: I think I've located the problem. It's in my converter, where I am trying to project to an object with nested objects and assign `null` to some of nested objects in some cases. I changed the code  and `Distinct` works well now. I posted update. I suspect that this happened because my converter wasn't translated to SQL and executed on objects rather than on entities.

Comment: @AunAun, try distilling the problem to the simplest possible representation (ie single column, remove filtering paging and sorting) - this could help others in future and might help people to give you an answer

Comment: How about distinct by a property `var projected = filtered
            .Select(converter)
            .Distinct(y=>y.YourKey);` Is that working

Answer (score 1):

From memory, the default `Distinct()` implementation works by using the default `Equals()` method for the respective class, which is often unwanted (I've found this to be the case with my work atleast).

You need to set up something like the following;

```
public class ProvidersViewModel : IEqualityComparer<ProvidersViewModel>
{
    public bool Equals(ProvidersViewModel x, ProvidersViewModel y)
    {
        if (x.col1 == y.col1 && x.col2 == y.col2 && x.col3 == y.col3)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(ProvidersViewModel obj)
    {
        int hCode = obj.col1 ^ obj.col2 ^ obj.col3;
        return hCode.GetHashCode();
    }

    // Existing code, fields, etc.
}
```

This should then allow the call to `Distinct()` to work properly.